# Find the number part of a filename if follows a certain pattern

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a script that will search for the words "ph" in the file name and if it will find it, it will store the ph+5 numbers after it.

At my work we give every job a number "ph32545" for example and I just want to check if the file name contains a ph number and store just that part in a variable.

This is what I have managed to do so far, the problem is that I don't know how to extract the ph number:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

var name = doc.name;
if (name.match("ph") == "ph") {alert("C1");}
```

the alert is just for testing to see if a ph has been found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just searching for `ph` will also give a match if a filename *by coincidence* contains these two letters. You should use a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to make sure that `ph` is followed by five digits.

It could look like this: `/ph\d{5}/`.

The RegExp must have a `/` first and last. `ph` is obviously the text string, `\d` means "any digit" and `{5}` means "five times". (You could also just have written `/ph\d\d\d\d\d/`, but that's a little longer.)

If you don't add a `g` for "global" after the RegExp, the `match` method only searches for the first match and returns an array where the first item is the found match.

If there isn't a match, the method will return `null`.

So your example should be like this:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var name = doc.name;
var match = name.match(/ph\d{5}/);
if (match) alert(match[0]);
```

Read more about [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

Comment: Thank you so much! it works. the real problem is that I don't really know where it's just javascript and where is illustrator coding stuff. I'm not really a programmer and I tried to check this stuff before I asked and it was like chinese to me =]

Comment: @goamalo I understand. In this example the only Illustrator related thing is the *Object* `app` which has a property called `activeDocument` (an *Object*) which has a property called `name` (a *String*).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I advanced in my code and I have found that I can't assign match to a variable and write it in a text frame. the text I get is "Array". why does it happen?